# Outputting the value from a JTextField using .getText()

Tags: java, jtextfield

I'm setting up a simple program that collects your name and then returns it in the console. The window opens successfully but when I enter text into '**jTextFieldPlayerName**' and press 'continue' The console prints `'Your name is: null'`. I am trying to make the console print out what you entered in 'jTextFieldPlayerName' (ex. Your name is: CrashDive) rather than 'Your name is: null'. -Thanks

```
package bin;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class main extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
protected JLabel text1;
protected JButton continue;
protected JTextField jTextFieldPlayerName;
protected String playerName;

public main() {

    text1 = new JLabel("<html><center>Before we can start we need to know your name.<br><html>");
    startText1.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.TOP);
    startText1.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);

    jTextFieldPlayerName = new JTextField();
    jTextFieldPlayerName.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,20));

    continue = new JButton("Continue");
    continue.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
    continue.addActionListener(this);
    continue.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    continue.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);

    add(text1);
    add(jTextFieldPlayerName);
    add(continue);

    String playerName = jTextFieldPlayerName.getText();
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    Object src = evt.getSource();

    if (src == startText1Continue && jTextFieldPlayerName.getText().length() > 0) {     
        System.out.println("Your name is: " +playerName);   
    }
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Game");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    main newContentPane = new main();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
    frame.setSize(1400, 700);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();  
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place `String playerName = jTextFieldPlayerName.getText();` inside **actionPerformed** method
as you are printing global **playerName** but it's never been initialized thats why it prints null.

You can do something like  below.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    Object src = evt.getSource();
    String playerName = jTextFieldPlayerName.getText();

    if (src == startText1Continue && playerName.length() > 0) {     
        System.out.println("Your name is: " +playerName);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont get a reference when you write "String playerName = jtextfieldPlayer.getText()", you assign playerName to the current return value from the getText-method, which at runtime is "".

Assign playerName at the actionEvent for the button instead.